# Can't find editable origin for form label in Kentico11 MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kentico-11

I have pages that are being dynamically created from custom data table. The problem is that there is also a webform on the page that needs a label edited. But because the page is dynamic and not in the "Pages" section of the CMS, I am unable to find a template or how to edit the label.

The page view model is not being used, I do not have the Design tab available to me to view templates.

I was expecting to find a template that includes the transform for the custom table data and to find a hard-coded form in the template that I would edit directly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.